# Update linphone in xamarin iOS project. Build error: Unknown command line argument

Tags: ios, xamarin, linphone

I used linphone (v. 3.12.0.281) in xamarin forms app. Now I'd like to update to the latest version and I change old frameworks to new ones (4.5.18) from linphone But my build for ios project ends with error:

Unknown command line argument: '/Users/user/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyApp.iOS/token/bin/iPhone/Release/MyApp.iOS.exe'.

If I remove linphone.framework from Native references my project build successfully (without opportunity to use linphone library). I build it in Visual Studio which paired to Mac. Some ideas why it doesn't build with older versions? (I tried to add different versions in my project but build ends with the same error).

Versions: Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 16.9.3; Xamarin.iOS 14.14.2.5; macOS Big Sur 11.5; XCode 12.5

Thank you.

Output:

```
3>------ Build started: Project: MyApp.iOS, Configuration: Release iPhone ------
3>  Executing SayHello Task to establish a connection to a Remote Server. 
3>              Properties: 
3>                  SessionId=3f62af169017bc02429d8f5fc2a45dbc2d7c02f3e7be7a8cd39b1998464fab18, 
3>                  ServerPort=52845, 
3>                  ServerAddress=192.168.2.203, 
3>                  ServerUser=user, 
3>                  ServerPassword=, 
3>                  SSHKey=, 
3>                  SSHPassPhrase=,
3>                  AppName=MyApp.iOS,
3>                  VisualStudioProcessId=26856,
3>                  ContinueOnDisconnected=False
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/add_24.png obj/iPhone/Release/optimized/add_24.png 
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/delete_24.png obj/iPhone/Release/optimized/delete_24.png 
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/dynamic_54.png obj/iPhone/Release/optimized/dynamic_54.png 
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/dynamic_act_54.png obj/iPhone/Release/optimized/dynamic_act_54.png 
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/off_bt_54.png obj/iPhone/Release/optimized/off_bt_54.png 
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/on_bt_54.png obj/iPhone/Release/optimized/on_bt_54.png 
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/un_lock_bt_54.png obj/iPhone/Release/optimized/un_lock_bt_54.png 
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/arrow_12.png obj/iPhone/Release/optimized/arrow_12.png 
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/apartment_24.png obj/iPhone/Release/optimized/apartment_24.png 
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/calls_24.png obj/iPhone/Release/optimized/calls_24.png 
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/info_24.png obj/iPhone/Release/optimized/info_24.png 
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/notification_24.png obj/iPhone/Release/optimized/notification_24.png 
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/settings_24.png obj/iPhone/Release/optimized/settings_24.png 
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/calendar_24.png obj/iPhone/Release/optimized/calendar_24.png 
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/missed_call_24.png obj/iPhone/Release/optimized/missed_call_24.png 
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/missed_call_buttakenbyanotherperson_24.png obj/iPhone/Release/optimized/missed_call_buttakenbyanotherperson_24.png 
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/rejected_call_24.png obj/iPhone/Release/optimized/rejected_call_24.png 
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/taken_call_24.png obj/iPhone/Release/optimized/taken_call_24.png 
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/arrow_grey_12.png obj/iPhone/Release/optimized/arrow_grey_12.png 
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/delete_grey_48.png obj/iPhone/Release/optimized/delete_grey_48.png 
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/missed_call_48.png obj/iPhone/Release/optimized/missed_call_48.png 
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/missed_call_buttakenbyanotherperson_48.png obj/iPhone/Release/optimized/missed_call_buttakenbyanotherperson_48.png 
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/rejected_call_48.png obj/iPhone/Release/optimized/rejected_call_48.png 
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/taken_call_48.png obj/iPhone/Release/optimized/taken_call_48.png 
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/camera.png obj/iPhone/Release/optimized/camera.png 
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/apartment_48.png obj/iPhone/Release/optimized/apartment_48.png 
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/calls_48.png obj/iPhone/Release/optimized/calls_48.png 
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/info_48.png obj/iPhone/Release/optimized/info_48.png 
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/notification_48.png obj/iPhone/Release/optimized/notification_48.png 
3>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/pngcrush -q -iphone -f 0 Resources/settings_48.png obj/iPhone/Release/optimized/settings_48.png 
3>  /usr/bin/plutil -convert binary1 -o obj/iPhone/Release/optimized/GoogleService-Info.plist GoogleService-Info.plist 
3>D:\Projects\App\src\MyApp.iOS\Call\SipCalliOS.cs(246,22,246,24): warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.
3>  MyApp.iOS -> D:\Projects\App\src\MyApp.iOS\bin\iPhone\Release\MyApp.iOS.exe
3>  Detected signing identity:
3>          
3>    Code Signing Key: "Apple Development: Olga Musienko (H79Z887SRT)" (63F88B015DB2474ECE5380E5464A36A531ADED12)
3>    Provisioning Profile: "VS: com.companyname.myapp Development" (664d1ec1-f90f-424d-9148-d8c5997ce450)
3>    Bundle Id: com.companyname.myapp
3>    App Id: 4E65FYK2LR.com.companyname.myapp
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(425,3): warning : [xma]: A timeout occurred on client build3f62af169017bc02429d8f5fc2a45dbc2d7c02f3e7be7a8cd39b1998464fab1820536musie while executing a post for topic xvs/build/compare-items
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(425,3): warning : The operation has timed out.
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(425,3): warning :    at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient.<PostAsync>d__21`2.MoveNext() in C:\A\1\230\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\MessagingClient.cs:line 185
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(425,3): warning : [xma]: A timeout occurred on client build3f62af169017bc02429d8f5fc2a45dbc2d7c02f3e7be7a8cd39b1998464fab1820536musie while executing a post for topic xvs/build/compare-items
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(425,3): warning : The operation has timed out.
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(425,3): warning :    at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient.<PostAsync>d__21`2.MoveNext() in C:\A\1\230\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\MessagingClient.cs:line 185
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(425,3): warning : A timeout occurred on client build3f62af169017bc02429d8f5fc2a45dbc2d7c02f3e7be7a8cd39b1998464fab1820536musie while executing a post for topic xvs/build/compare-items
3>  /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mtouch @/Users/user/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyApp.iOS/3f62af169017bc02429d8f5fc2a45dbc2d7c02f3e7be7a8cd39b1998464fab18/obj/iPhone/Release/response-file.rsp --optimize=experimental-xforms-product-type "--gcc_flags=-ObjC -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz -ObjC -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz" 
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(425,3): error MT0018: Unknown command line argument: '/Users/user/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyApp.iOS/3f62af169017bc02429d8f5fc2a45dbc2d7c02f3e7be7a8cd39b1998464fab18/bin/iPhone/Release/MyApp.iOS.exe'
```

Comment: Seems like you've posted a partial error message, please provide more context.

Comment: @Cheesebaron The message in Error List looks exactly like in the question. And I added Output messages to give more context. What should I add else to complete the description?

Comment: Have you tried building directly on the mac?

Comment: @Cheesebaron Yes, I have tried building directly on the mac and it is successfully. Thank you so much! But I have mac virtual machine and it builds so slowly. May be should I add some flags or something in settings for pair to Mac to build in Visual Studio for Windows? Do you have some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This refers to the exe file being missing. It is most likely caused by the Antivirus software deleting the created exe file, and that's why mtouch cannot find it.